# Order by date on a select distinct query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting data from a temp table for email body bu this query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110)) as Ingestion_date,
            a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,
            a.INVOICE_TYPE, 
            COUNT (a.RECORD_TYPE_CD)    
 FROM @report_invoices a , @report_invoices b 
 WHERE  (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 103)) = (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), b.ORIG_DT, 103)) 
       AND a.RECORD_TYPE_CD = b.RECORD_TYPE_CD 
       and a.INVOICE_TYPE = b.INVOICE_TYPE 
GROUP BY  (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110)) ,
          a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,
          a.INVOICE_TYPE 
ORDER BY Ingestion_date
```

but having problem on order bay date.

Getting this order

```
01-04-2017  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  1
01-12-2017  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  1
01-13-2017  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  25
01-18-2017  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  36
01-23-2017  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  1
01-24-2017  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  1
03-13-2017  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  1
05-16-2017  Invoice electronic uploads  1
12-05-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  9
12-06-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  961
12-06-2016  Serengeti   Iron Mountain uploaded  1
12-07-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  196
12-08-2016  Invoice Iron Mountain uploaded  36
12-09-2016  Invoice Iron Mountain uploaded  289
12-14-2016  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  64
12-15-2016  CheckRequest    electronic uploads  1
12-15-2016  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  144
12-16-2016  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  36
12-19-2016  CheckRequest    electronic uploads  81
12-19-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  9
12-20-2016  CheckRequest    electronic uploads  9
12-20-2016  Invoice Iron Mountain uploaded  1
12-20-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  484
12-21-2016  CheckRequest    electronic uploads  1
12-21-2016  ImportedHistory Iron Mountain uploaded  9
12-21-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  64
12-22-2016  CheckRequest    electronic uploads  36
12-22-2016  PCard   Iron Mountain uploaded  1
12-23-2016  CheckRequest    electronic uploads  4
```

need to correct the order

Comment: try order by a.ORIG_DT and check the output

Comment: what do you mean by correct the order? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Paresh it is giving error 
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: JanR the date order is not on full date it is only ordering on month

Comment: you are ordering it as a string rather a date type

Comment: Else it is not working with group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't sort by a column that doesn't exist in distinct query, you need to do something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(10), ORIG_DT, 110) as Ingestion_date,RECORD_TYPE_CD,INVOICE_TYPE, RECORD_COUNT   
from ( 
    select
    convert(date, a.ORIG_DT) as ORIG_DT,a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,a.INVOICE_TYPE, COUNT (a.RECORD_TYPE_CD) as RECORD_COUNT
    @report_invoices a , @report_invoices b 
    where CONVERT (date, a.ORIG_DT) = CONVERT (date, b.ORIG_DT, 103) AND a.RECORD_TYPE_CD = b.RECORD_TYPE_CD 
    and a.INVOICE_TYPE = b.INVOICE_TYPE GROUP BY convert(date, a.ORIG_DT), a.RECORD_TYPE_CD, a.INVOICE_TYPE 
) X
ORDER BY ORIG_DT
```

Comment: it is Still the same

Comment: There were few aliases left there that I fixed, have you tried the latest version? It definitely should work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `distinct` keyword since you are already using `group by` on all the columns except for the `count` in the select list.
This means that you can use `a.ORIG_DT` in the order by clause:

```
 SELECT CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110) as Ingestion_date,
        a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,
        a.INVOICE_TYPE, 
        COUNT (a.RECORD_TYPE_CD)    
 FROM @report_invoices a , @report_invoices b 
 WHERE  (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 103)) = (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), b.ORIG_DT, 103)) 
       AND a.RECORD_TYPE_CD = b.RECORD_TYPE_CD 
       and a.INVOICE_TYPE = b.INVOICE_TYPE 
GROUP BY  (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110)) ,
          a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,
          a.INVOICE_TYPE 
ORDER BY a.ORIG_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use same format in select and order by also :

```
SELECT DISTINCT (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110)) as Ingestion_date,
        a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,
        a.INVOICE_TYPE, 
        COUNT (a.RECORD_TYPE_CD)    
FROM @report_invoices a , @report_invoices b 
WHERE  (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 103)) = (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), 
 b.ORIG_DT, 103)) AND a.RECORD_TYPE_CD = b.RECORD_TYPE_CD 
 and a.INVOICE_TYPE = b.INVOICE_TYPE 
 GROUP BY  (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110)) ,
 a.RECORD_TYPE_CD,a.INVOICE_TYPE 
 ORDER BY (CONVERT (nvarchar(10), a.ORIG_DT, 110))
```

Comment: This won't fix it. The problem is that it's performing a textual sort rather than a date sort, on a date format that doesn't also guarantee to work when sorted as text. E.g. if they were converting to `yyyymmdd` or similar variants then it wouldn't be an issue. But since they're converting to `mm-dd-yyyy`, you can't sort that text sensibly.